# expected `&i64`, found `user_id`

Tags: rust

I want to pass the i64 user_id to another function, this is the function defined like:

```
#![allow(unused)]
#![allow(clippy::all)]

use rust_wheel::common::util::time_util::get_current_millisecond;
use serde::Serialize;
use serde::Deserialize;
use uuid::Uuid;
use crate::model::diesel::tex::tex_schema::*;

#[derive(Insertable,Queryable,QueryableByName,Debug,Serialize,Deserialize,Default,Clone)]
#[diesel(table_name = tex_project)]
pub struct TexProjectAdd {
    pub doc_name: String,
    pub created_time: i64,
    pub updated_time: i64,
    pub user_id: i64,
    pub doc_status: i32,
    pub template_id: i64,
    pub project_id: String,
}

impl TexProjectAdd {
    pub(crate) fn from_req(prj_name: &String, user_id: &i64) ->Self {
        let uuid = Uuid::new_v4();
        let uuid_string = uuid.to_string().replace("-", "");
        Self {
            doc_name: prj_name.to_string(),
            created_time: get_current_millisecond(),
            updated_time: get_current_millisecond(),
            user_id: user_id.to_owned(),
            doc_status: 1,
            template_id: 1,
            project_id: uuid_string
        }
    }
}
```

when I using this function to pass the value:

```
fn create_proj(
    proj_name: &String,
    connection: &mut PgConnection,
    user_id: &i64
) -> Result<TexProject, diesel::result::Error> {
    let new_proj = TexProjectAdd::from_req(proj_name, user_id);
    use crate::model::diesel::tex::tex_schema::tex_project::dsl::*;
    let result = diesel::insert_into(tex_project)
        .values(&new_proj)
        .get_result::<TexProject>(connection);
    return result;
}
```

shows error like this:

```
    error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/service/project/project_service.rs:99:55
   |
99 |     let new_proj = TexProjectAdd::from_req(proj_name, user_id);
   |                    -----------------------            ^^^^^^^ expected `&i64`, found `user_id`
   |                    |
   |                    arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
note: associated function defined here
  --> src/model/diesel/custom/project/tex_project_add.rs:23:19
   |
23 |     pub(crate) fn from_req(prj_name: &String, user_id: &i64) ->Self {
   |                   ^^^^^^^^                    -------------

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue?

Comment: You aren’t passing it as a reference

Comment: And you don’t need it to be one

Comment: I already pass the user id as & from the parent function.  @DanielA.White

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your import from `tex_project::dsl::*` includes a `user_id` unit type generated from the `table!` definition which will shadow the existing `user_id` parameter. In this case you only need the table itself to insert into so remove the wildcard:

```
use crate::model::diesel::tex::tex_schema::tex_project::dsl::tex_project;
let result = diesel::insert_into(tex_project)
    .values(&new_proj)
    .get_result::<TexProject>(connection);

// or

use crate::model::diesel::tex::tex_schema::tex_project;
let result = diesel::insert_into(tex_project::table)
    .values(&new_proj)
    .get_result::<TexProject>(connection);
```

I prefer the latter and personally avoid using `dsl::*` altogether due to name conflicts like this.

For more context: imports can be done anywhere in a scope and they will be available in the whole scope; it doesn't matter where or in which order imports are declared. So the fact that the `use tex_project::dsl::*` comes after `from_req(proj_name, user_id)` doesn't matter. Its the same as if you did the import first. And the function body scope is a slightly smaller scope than the function parameters (see [drop scopes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html#drop-scopes)), so the import shadows the parameter and not the other way around or end up as a conflict. Only later when you try to use the `user_id` parameter.

[Reproduction link to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5bde693ef3a188eb4f03d9a63665dfb4) even though Diesel isn't available there.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might benefit from a reproducible testcase. The following works fine in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/):

```
pub struct TexProjectAdd{pub user_id: i64}
impl TexProjectAdd {
    fn from_req(user_id: &i64) -> Self {
        Self {user_id: user_id.to_owned()}
    }
}
fn create_proj(user_id: &i64) {
    let x = TexProjectAdd::from_req(user_id);
    let y = x.user_id;
    println!("{y:#?}")    
}
fn main() {
    let y = 1i64;
    create_proj(&y)
}
```

It's also a little weird that the error message says `found user_id`, not `found (some type)`...

Comment: yes, the user_id was a variable not a type.